# String Concatenation in project code of java

Tags: android

Question :

```
txtTitle.setText(foodItem.getItemName () + "  " + foodItem.getItemCode());
```

This is a part of my project, I must get the output as fooditem (itemcode),eg: ChickenBiriyani(CB01), like this, my question is where to put that bracket of Itemcode in this,please clarify??

Answer (score 0):

```
txtTitle.setText(foodItem.getItemName () + " (" + foodItem.getItemCode() +")");
```

Answer (score 0):

It fair simple:

```
txtTitle.setText(foodItem.getItemName () + " ( " + foodItem.getItemCode() + " ) ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement like below:

```
txtTitle.setText(foodItem.getItemName() + " (" + foodItem.getItemCode() + ")");
```

This above statement will result you:
ChickenBiriyani(CB01) Where **ChickenBiriyani** is coming from foodItem.getItemName() and **CB01** is coming from foodItem.getItemCode()